# Using the return value of a function as the value in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, function, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm creating a python application that requires a user to log into a web service.  The credentials are passed to the server in a POST request as a json dictionary.  In order to avoid unnecessarily saving the password in a variable I figured I would do something like the following:

`json.dumps({'username': raw_input('Username: '), 'password': getpass.getpass()})`

1. Is there any guarantee that `raw_input` will get called before `getpass`?
2. Is there actually any benefit in this method over saving the output of the functions first and then creating the dictionary from the variables?
3. Is this a 'pythonic' way of doing things?  My guess is no since there is a lot of stuff crammed into a single line and it's arguably not very readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes , since python is evaluated left to right like english. the functions will be called left to right.
2. its slightly shorter
3. not super pythonic but not aweful either

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insure `raw_input()` called before `getpass()`, I think you should use variables like this:

```
username = raw_input('Username: ')
passwd = getpass.getpass()

user_dict = {username : passwd}
```

Use variable will make your code more readable and easy to maintenance or debug.

First, the code will be execute as `raw_input('Username: ')` then `getpass.getpass()` make a dict at last.

Second, it's more shorter and if your program is small and easy that's a good way .

Third, it's short, kind of pythonic I guess but not good in engineering side.

Comment: I agree this looks slightly nicer, however it does not answer the questions the OP asked. (I gave you +1 all the same)